# Javascript element is null

Tags: javascript

I am a begginer at javascrit, and im trying to get a form result globaly

the radio button

```
<input type='radio' name='supporter' id='supporter' value='yes'>
```

and the javascript on the nother page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(){
    var supporter = document.getElementById('supporter');
    if (supporter.value == "yes") {
        alert("it works")
    }
}

show();
</script>
```

and i keep getting an error, this: supporter is null

can please someone tell me what im missing?

Comment: Is this javascript on a different page from the radio button? Because that won't work.

Comment: i have not any problem with your javascript http://jsfiddle.net/Awea/Y5hNw/ just a missed semicolon :p

Comment: @Awea, still works even without semicolon

Comment: @domanokz, i know http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-10-javascript-mistakes-youre-making/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+nettuts+%28Nettuts%2B%29 a good article

Comment: @Awea What I meant is its still working, I didn't say its a good practice, me either use semicolon. And, I didn't mean to offend or something. :)

Comment: @domanokz don't worry i didn't take it for offense, my english is just no so good :p

Answer (score 7):

It will depend on *when* the script is executed. Javascript is executed by the browser as it is encountered, which means that if your snippet of code exists in the page *before* the HTML element, then at that point in time, the HTML element does not yet exist.

One solution would be to put the Javascript at the very end of the page, or move that code into the `document.onload` handler.

```
document.onload = function () {
    show();
};
```

Comment: Never put script elements in the body element, it encourages poor programming habits and leads to a complete lack of organization code-wise. If you don't have the time to do it the right way then don't do it at all.

Answer (score 3):

You are likely running that script before the `<input>` element is reached in your code, so it doesn't exist when you try to access it. Make sure that your script comes after your input (or you wrap your script in a document onload event handler so that it doesn't execute until the page has fully loaded)

Answer (score 3):

Put this after or below input element. The input element wasn't loaded yet and the javascript is executed so you get null.

Solution 1:

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
    <input id="supporter" value="yes" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show()
    {
        var supporter = document.getElementById('supporter');
     if (supporter.value == "yes") 
         {
          alert("it works")
         }
    }

    show();
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Solution 2:

Or if you preffer putting scripts in the head of html, run the function only when the page is loaded.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="yourcodes.js">
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <input id="supporter" value="yes" />
</body>
</html>
```

On your separate javascript page:

```
function show()
{
    var supporter = document.getElementById('supporter');
     if (supporter.value == "yes") 
     {
       alert("it works");
     }
}

//When page loaded
document.onload = function(){
    show();
};
```

Note: you don't have to put `<script></script>` in your JavaScript file.

Comment: thank you for the help, and for spending time on me, but no matter what i try nothing helps, but thanks

Comment: @Side: domanokz' solution works very well: http://jsfiddle.net/NfJVc/

Comment: @Felix, I think he's really missing something.

Comment: i think to, now i wont get the script error but the alert- isnt popping up and no errors

Comment: @Side Did your `src` set correctly? The solution two should work correctly. If you are using IE and you see a yellow bar at the top of the browser, maybe it's blocking the pop-up.

Comment: yes the src is correct checked it, no im useing FF

Comment: no its not blocking the popup, im really lost a bit